# Can an MQTT subscriber detect if a retained message was sent in response to the subscription?

Tags: mqtt

When an MQTT client subscribes to a topic that has retained messages, it will immediately receive those messages.

If new retained messages are published on the topic it will also receive those.

Is there a way for the client to distinguish between both cases? I.e. can it know if a particular received message was published just now or if it was retained and re-delivered by the broker?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the MQTT Specification [here](http://docs.oasis-open.org/mqtt/mqtt/v3.1.1/os/mqtt-v3.1.1-os.html#_Toc398718038):

> When sending a PUBLISH Packet to a Client the Server MUST set the
> RETAIN flag to 1 if a message is sent as a result of a new
> subscription being made by a Client [MQTT-3.3.1-8]. It MUST set the
> RETAIN flag to 0 when a PUBLISH Packet is sent to a Client because it
> matches an established subscription regardless of how the flag was set
> in the message it received [MQTT-3.3.1-9].

This means that for messages that are the result of being delivered first at the point of subscription they should have the header flag set.

How this is made known to the client will depend on the client library it is using.

Comment: Oh, so the `retain` flag can be false in the received message even though it was published with `retain`, I didn't know that.